# SVG Viewer causing IE8 to hang when browser is zoomed

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg, frames

We have a website that currently serves drawings to users via the SVG Viewer plugin.  We have one client that sees it through IE8.  With IE8, when they do a Change Zoom Level on the browser to anything other then 100%, the viewer tries to occupy the new space and zooms correctly.  However, when the user tries to manipulate the frames inside that bound the viewer (it's a frameset website with the viewer being in the center) the entire site hangs.  IE8 also shows that it takes up CPU cycles on the client computer, so it's trying to do something but hitting a loop.

I don't think this is actually our code and might just be something with SVG and how IE8 handles plugins and it's zoom.  Does anyone know if this is a real problem and if there's a good solution?

Comment: By "the SVG Viewer plugin" are you referring to the [Adobe SVG Viewer](http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/)? The one that was last improved almost 10 years ago, had a bug fix release 6 years ago, and for which all support was [fully discontinued](http://www.adobe.com/svg/eol.html) 2 years ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.  I thought it was the SVG viewer trying to do something with the frames, when it turned out that I was just setting the frameset's initial size to the clientHeight and clientWidth, and then subtracting something from the height.  That subtraction was a toolbar based in the frameset and, when you change the zoom level in the browser, there's a lock up that can occur with you trying to pull a components size and the client's size.  At least, this is what I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Adobe SVG Viewer plug-in, then I recommend that you (ideally) get your clients to start using a web browser that supports SVG natively — i.e. Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera; even IE9 (to some extent) — or use a different shim like [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) to provide SVG [support for those users of older browsers](http://www.rustybrick.com/svg-support-for-internet-explorer.html) who also have Flash installed.

Comment: We have a lot of small reasons why we can't switch browsers.  Our client is big enough and picky enough that they have to use IE8 to use our service and won't switch.  Also, we have a lot of legacy code behind this because it was meant to process very large SVGs that were zipped into SVGZ format.  So far, all of the side tools I've looked for do not support zipped SVGs.  This might boil down to us telling the client that they HAVE to use our new system, which is natively Flash drawings anyways.  I'm just making sure there are no other solutions to our complex problem.

Comment: @CrystalBlue It sounds like you're saying that you have to use IE8 and you have to use the Adobe SVG Viewer. Given that this combination is failing, I cannot think of any other solution for you. Sorry.